# How to Recover an Aborted Rebase

Tags: git, rebase, abort

I was working on a list of rebases and did `git add`, made changes, then `rebase --continue`.

however, during this I accidentally typed `rebase --abort.`

I want to continue to do the rebase that I accidentally aborted so I did 
   `git reflog`

and then

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
```

The problem is if I type git `rebase --continue` it says I have no rebase in progress and that I

`have 1 and 10 different commits each, respectively (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)`

Is there anyway I can go back and continue the rebase or do I need to pull from the branch and redo it?

Answer (score 2):

First things first: You do *not* want to do a git pull at this point.  You could recover even if you did, but it will be taking you in the wrong direction[1].

So the steps you followed correctly recovered the changes that had been committed during the previous rebase attempt - which may be useful.

But that's not the same as putting git back into a rebasing state.  There are other things going on - e.g. git is managing a todo list of patches representing the original commits.

As far as I know, there isn't really a way to restart a rebase that's been aborted.  But you can approximate it using `rebase --onto`.

(a) from the tip of the old rebase (where you had reset to) create a tag

(b) reset back to where the branch was before the rebase.  (You can again find this in the reflog; it's where the `rebase --abort` sent you.)

(c) now, supposing you have

```
x -- A -- B -- C -- D <--(branch)
 \
  x -- x -- o <--(master)
             \
              A' -- B' <-rebase_tag
```

where `rebase_tag` is the tag you created at the tip of the old rebase attempt, so `A'` is the rewrite of `A`, `B'` is the rewrite of `B`, and you still need to rewrite `C` and `D`.

What you want to do is rewrite `C` and `D` onto `B'`.  So

```
git rebase --onto rebase_tag branch~2 branch
```

Here, `branch~2` can be replaced with any expression that resolves to `B` (the last of the original commits that has been rewritten in the previous rebase attempt).

Of course, if the work related to the original rebase attempt is minimal - if it didn't take much time and there wasn't a lot of complicated merge resolution going on - you *could* just restart from scratch.  Even doing that, you could use the "old rewritten commits' as reference when resolving conflicts.

But assuming it's clear to you how to calculate the expression for the `--onto` parameter, the above is probably the easiest way to "restart' the rebase.

---

[1] The thing to understand here is, certain git commands give very detailed/specific advice; but that advice is written to address the common use cases, where you've done certain things they assume a new user would usually do.  It's fine that you do things that don't fit those assumptions, but they assume that anyone who does knows enough to not need the specific/detailed advice.

So what's happened is, you've done something outside those assumptions, so the `pull` advice doesn't apply; if you follow it, you'll be heading further in the wrong direction.  Not that you couldn't still recover - you could - but it would be even more confusing.